# ios email application

Tags: iphone, ios

I am looking for help, I am new to iphone programming

Is there a way to send an email, using standard account configured on the device WITHOUT opening a compose UI, without Pagesheet?

I want to write an app to send me email reminders.

looking forward to hearing a replay from you

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Is there a way to send an email, using standard account configured on the device **WITHOUT opening a compose UI**

No you can not.

Alternative way :

You can write a web service that sends emails to specific address.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to send the information to a server you manage and just send the email through smtp type method.

Comment: i dont understand what u say..? please help me

Comment: @MaulikVekariya He is saying that just create webservice and send an email through there.

Answer (score 1):

You can sent the email in background witj out using any composer window

See [this **SMTPSender**](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/source/browse/#svn/trunk/SMTPSender) example

Example:

```
- (BOOL)send
{
    NSAssert(sendState == kSKPSMTPIdle, @"Message has already been sent!");

    if (requiresAuth)
    {
        NSAssert(login, @"auth requires login");
        NSAssert(pass, @"auth requires pass");
    }

    NSAssert(relayHost, @"send requires relayHost");
    NSAssert(subject, @"send requires subject");
    NSAssert(fromEmail, @"send requires fromEmail");
    NSAssert(toEmail, @"send requires toEmail");
    NSAssert(parts, @"send requires parts");

    if (![relayPorts count])
    {
        [delegate messageFailed:self
                          error:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"SKPSMTPMessageError"
                                                    code:kSKPSMTPErrorConnectionFailed
                                                userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSLocalizedString(@"Unable to connect to the server.", @"server connection fail error description"),NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,
                                                          NSLocalizedString(@"Try sending your message again later.", @"server generic error recovery"),NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey,nil]]];

        return NO;
    }

    // Grab the next relay port
    short relayPort = [[relayPorts objectAtIndex:0] shortValue];

    // Pop this off the head of the queue.
    self.relayPorts = ([relayPorts count] > 1) ? [relayPorts subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [relayPorts count] - 1)] : [NSArray array];

    NSLog(@"C: Attempting to connect to server at: %@:%d", relayHost, relayPort);

    self.connectTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:connectTimeout
                                                         target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(connectionConnectedCheck:)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:NO];

    [NSStream getStreamsToHostNamed:relayHost port:relayPort inputStream:&inputStream outputStream:&outputStream];
    if ((inputStream != nil) && (outputStream != nil))
    {
        sendState = kSKPSMTPConnecting;
        isSecure = NO;

        [inputStream retain];
        [outputStream retain];

        [inputStream setDelegate:self];
        [outputStream setDelegate:self];

        [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                               forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                                forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [inputStream open];
        [outputStream open];

        self.inputString = [NSMutableString string];



        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [self.connectTimer invalidate];
        self.connectTimer = nil;

        [delegate messageFailed:self
                          error:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"SKPSMTPMessageError"
                                                    code:kSKPSMTPErrorConnectionFailed
                                                userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSLocalizedString(@"Unable to connect to the server.", @"server connection fail error description"),NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,
                                                          NSLocalizedString(@"Try sending your message again later.", @"server generic error recovery"),NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey,nil]]];

        return NO;
    }
}
```